# Strange behaviour for jQuery find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this piece of javascript that works perfectly to one of my websites but give troubles with other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($.find(Thesaurus.options.containers).length > 0) {
            thes = new Thesaurus(Thesaurus.options);
        }
});
```

These are results when I try to debug by using the old fashioned alerts:

- `alert(Thesaurus.options.containers);` - this returns the string **div.content**
- `alert($.find(Thesaurus.options.containers));` - this one returns **empty**, therefore the length is zero
- `alert($.find('div.content'));` - this one returns **[object HTMLdivElement]** as I expect

I seem to be unable to understand what is happening.

Comment: What is `$.find`? I have not seen it in jQuery. Please enlighten me

Comment: `$.find` is not a public API; it's a reference to Sizzle.  It should not be used.

Comment: my bad. however something is spooky there since the correct answer while it is working, it returns [object Object] not [object HTMLdivElement] as it should, so further processing is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method `$.find()` in jQuery it's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($(document).find(Thesaurus.options.containers).length > 0) {
            thes = new Thesaurus(Thesaurus.options);
        }
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($(Thesaurus.options.containers).length > 0) {
            thes = new Thesaurus(Thesaurus.options);
        }
});
```

Comment: ... or simply `$(Thesaurus.options.containers)`

Comment: good. the simplified form works correctly, however this happens:

alert($(Thesaurus.options.containers)); returns [object Object] instead of [object HTMLdivElement]

Any idea?

Comment: @RichardVencu the return value from a jQuery call is *supposed* to be an object (a jQuery object), not a DOM node.

Comment: thanks. I fixed the issue by hardcoding a variable into the javascript function (ugly). The experiment is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586200/jquery-selectors-troubles

Answer (score 0):

If you visit web page of jQUery you can visualize that you are using wrong $.find... here an example the way to use.

```
 <ul class="level-1">
 <li class="item-i">I</li>
 <li class="item-ii">II
 <ul class="level-2">
 <li class="item-a">A</li>
 <li class="item-b">B
 <ul class="level-3">
 <li class="item-1">1</li>
 <li class="item-2">2</li>
 <li class="item-3">3</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="item-c">C</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="item-iii">III</li>
 </ul>
```

If we begin at item II, we can find list items within it:
1

```
$( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

you need to change your code something like this:

```
   if ($(document).find(Thesaurus.options.containers).length > 0) {
        thes = new Thesaurus(Thesaurus.options);
    }
```

Hope this works.

Regards