# jQuery selectors troubles

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need help to understand why these things behave strange:

```
alert($('div.entry').text());                   returns some long text
alert(Thesaurus.options.containers);            returns string div.entry
alert($(Thesaurus.options.containers).text());  breaks with Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The HTML has under 500 words in few div.entry elements.

The Thesaurus.options.containers looks like this:

```
jQuery.Thesaurus({
        caseSentitive: false,
        zetind: 'auto',
        delay: 250, 
        containers: ['div.entry'],
        effect: 'slide',
...
```

Comment: what if you call `$(Thesaurus.options.containers[0]).text()`

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing the HTML you're using this on.

Comment: It's better to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. `console.log()` would have shown you that `Thesaurus.options.containers` contains an array with a single string. The `alert()` joined the values in the array on a comma, which in your case made it look like the value was a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you're doing this: `$(['div.entry]).text();` I'm guessing since you're passing an array that you're calling this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray which is meant to take an array of *elements*, not an array of selectors. You can see this blow up here: http://jsfiddle.net/dE9Yb/.

What you could do instead is this:

```
alert($(Thesaurus.options.containers.join(",")).text());
```

So, pass in one string that is a selector joined by commas.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/dE9Yb/1/